# AMPscript Function Reference inside a CONCAT

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to multiply one value and show the result of that multiplication in the copy of my mail. The thing is that depending the value, the copy changes. So I made this ampscript:

```
%%[ 
VAR @saldo, @nombre, @copy, @conversion 

SET @nombre = AttributeValue ('nombre') 
SET @conversion = 0.01 
SET @saldo = AttributeValue ('balance_cuenta')

if @saldo>= 39999 then SET @copy = CONCAT("tienes: " , @saldo, " puntos,  equivalentes a $%%=Multiply(@balance_cuenta,@saldo)=%% USD.
¡Úsalos con esta promo!")

else SET @copy = CONCAT("¡Suma puntos con esta promo!") 

ENDIF ]%%
```

---

The problem is that the multiply function doesn't show the result, it shows in text: `"$%%=Multiply(@balance_cuenta,@saldo)=%%"`.

Is there a way to do this inside an AMPSCRIPT?

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use %% within an already opened ampscript block. The best way to correct this is to simply set a variable @value (Set @value = Multiply(...)) before your Concat copy line. You can then easily use @value as part of your Concat function.

Comment: I try this and it didn't work... that what you meant? %%[ VAR @ saldo, @ copy, @ conversion, @ valorpuntos SET @ saldo = AttributeValue ('balance_cuenta') SET @ valorpuntos = 0.01 SET @ conversion = Multiply(@ saldo,@ valorpuntos) if @ saldo>= 39999 then SET @ copy = CONCAT("tienes: " , @ saldo, " puntos, equivalentes a @ conversion ¡Úsalos con esta promo!") else SET @ copy = CONCAT("¡Suma puntos con esta promo!") ENDIF ]%%

Comment: I just realized that you didn't set a variable named balance_cuenta. Could it be that you actually want to multiply conversion (instead of balance_cuenta) and saldo? That would make more sense if my interpretation is correct that you want to calculate a point score based on the balance.

Comment: The line with the conversion variable also misses '. It needs to look like this as you are using a static value: SET @conversion = '0.01'

Comment: Yep, that value was missing. I already changed it and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest an inline Ampscript %%= within an Ampscript block %%[

Try changing you Concat function to :

```
if @saldo>= 39999 then SET @copy = CONCAT("tienes: " , @saldo, " puntos, equivalentes a $",Multiply(@balance_cuenta,@saldo)," USD. ¡Úsalos con esta promo!")
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for confirming. Upvotes are always appreciated